# How to avoid creating Spark Session for every script

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 7 different .py files on my local machine containing PySpark code and I've to run them randomly on-demand. Everytime I run the .py it creates the spark session, runs the job and then terminates and same happens for the new script as well. Is there any way to keep spark session up and running and I can just submit my required .py file to it and it provides me with the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could download Spark from [its website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), and start a Spark server in standalone mode:

```
$ tar zxf spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz && cd spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
$ ./sbin/start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /somewhere/logs/xxx.out

$ tail -f /somewhere/logs/xxx.out
21/08/04 17:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: edwin_liu
21/08/04 17:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
21/08/04 17:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
21/08/04 17:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disa....
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://YOUR-HOST:7077
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO Master: Running Spark version 3.1.2
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://YOUR-HOST:8080
21/08/04 17:30:01 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

Then you can submit your scripts via command line:

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://YOUR-HOST:7077 /path/to/script.py
```

or execute them directly:

```
$ cat /path/to/script.py
...
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://YOUR-HOST:7077").appName("xxx").getOrCreate()
...

$ python /path/to/script.py
```

##### References

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html